# Searching records from database with AND and OR operators

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently working on searching records from the database with the advance search. I also create the script for that, in which I am using the `OR` operator with the `BETWEEN` query but I am confused with how can I use the asking rate from minimum to maximum. How can I use the `AND` an `OR` operator with MySQL search query like `BETWEEN`?

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM meta WHERE title='$title' OR 
        discription='$discription' OR region='$region' OR city='$city' OR 
        sector='$sector' OR minimum='$minimum' OR mini='$mini' OR minni='$minni'"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM meta WHERE  
        (
           title='$title' OR 
           discription='$discription' OR region='$region' OR city='$city' OR 
           sector='$sector' OR minimum='$minimum' OR mini='$mini' OR minni='$minni' 
        ) -- Atleast one of the above or conditions must be true
        AND  (date between '$start_date' and '$end_date');
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM meta WHERE  
        (
           title='$title' OR 
           discription='$discription' OR region='$region' OR city='$city' OR 
           sector='$sector' OR minimum='$minimum' OR mini='$mini' OR minni='$minni' 
        ) -- Atleast one of the above or conditions must be true
        AND  (date > '$start_date' and date < '$end_date');
```

Comment: fantastic reply from you @ Nishanthi Grashia so thanks but this is not showing the all records between the range of minimum and maximum ! but thanks

Comment: @rajkumar: you need to use trunc/trim/ to_char function as appropriate when using date functions and between...

Comment: @  Nishanthi Grashia ,actually i want to display the particular column's entries between minimum to maximum with a search field Ex. if we enter the 10 in the minimum field and 100 into the maximum field than all records between ten and 100 should be displaying , and these entries should be in the  only one column's from the database with particular name suppose business range , any way thanks i will tried to modifying this one , your reply suggesting to me for do something with new clue .Thanks

Comment: Ok.. let me know if you need further help... You can upvote and accept as answer cos it helped you...

Comment: when we press the search button without entries the all records should be shown there? please help

Comment: just add aditional `OR 1=1` as a condition

Answer (score 0):

OR ('$var' > minimum AND '$var' < maximum)

Answer (score 0):

```
OR ('$var' BETWEEN minimum AND maximum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use between like

select * from meta where title='$title' and (date between '$start_date' and '$end_date').